# In Swift, is it a good practice to declare variables with a value assigned?

Tags: swift, memory-management

Is it a good practice to declare variables with default value like :

```
var myBoolean = false
```

Or is it better to initialize a value in a view lifecycle method like viewDidLoad or other delegate.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.myBoolean = false
}
```

I wonder if one of them is better in terms of memory usage.

(I understand that if you wanted the variable to be set to a value when view appears each time, you could use viewWillAppear).

Comment: Be aware not to confuse optional variables with non optional ones.

Answer (score 6):

> Or is it better to initialize a value in a view lifecycle method like viewDidLoad

It isn't "better". It is impossible.

You cannot initialize `self.myBoolean` by your second code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.myBoolean = false
}
```

By the time we get to `viewDidLoad`, any instance variables such as `self.myBoolean` have already been initialized, because they had to be initialized when `self` was created, which has already happened. Thus, by definition, your code is *not* initializing `self.myBoolean`; it is overwriting its already existing value. It was initialized earlier, in some other way.

*All* stored instance variables *must* have an initial value, assigned either in the same line as the declaration or through an `init`. There is no other way, and neither is more efficient than the other.

Comment: You could also mention the behavior of optional variables and constructor initialized variables.

Comment: @Passe I have mentioned them elsewhere. At present let’s focus on the examples in the question.